# Wacom Bamboo Pen scaling issues

Tags: 11.04, wacom, bamboo

I recently purchased a Wacom Bamboo Pen. It worked out of the box with Ubuntu Natty Narwhal, but I'm annoyed with the fact that the tablet is proportional to the screen. This makes a little line on the tablet show up as a large line on my screen (I'm using xournal). Is there a way to make it so that there is no scaling between my screen and the tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question for future readers:

You want to use the [xsetwacom](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Xsetwacom) program and place it in your .xinitrc file in your home folder. The setting you want to use is called 'stylus' and the value should be set to 'Area'. Like so:

```
xsetwacom set stylus Area 0 0 1024 768
xsetwacom set eraser Area 0 0 1024 768
```

For example will set the area that the stylus device works in to be within those co-ordinates. You may also be interested in the non absolute setting which allows a different way of working with the pen.

Comment: .xinitrc? Where does this live, I couldnt find it with a
'find / -name .xinitrc'
Up to now, I've just had a shell script sitting on my desktop and I execute it whenever I plug in the tablet. It's not too bad, but auto would be a definite improvement.

Just to add to your post -- people will probably want to accompany the 'stylus' line with an 'eraser' one, too

Comment: mark - It's a file you must create, it's a script file so it's just as you do now but it's run on xorg login, I'm not sure if it works when you plug/unplug the device, maybe you can test that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you really want mouse mode, or perhaps pressure sensitive settings are what you are looking for.  Whatever the case, hope https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom helps.  Good luck.

Comment: I found out that 'xsetwacom set stylus Area' can get me what I want, but now I just need to figure out how it works screen coordinates. [xsetwacom](http://kishalmi.net/cms/node/90)