# Can I change the vertical scaling independent from the horizontal scaling when using my Bamboo stylus in Relative mode?

Tags: 11.04, wacom, bamboo

Can I change the vertical scaling independent from the horizontal scaling when using my stylus in Relative mode?

I use a Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch, with the stylus in Relative mode (instead of the default Absolute). I use two monitors side-by-side, giving me a screen area of 3840x1080 pixels (3.5 aspect ratio). The tablet is 14720x9200 "units" (1.6 aspect ratio).

If I move my stylus 1 cm in the horizontal direction it will move much further on the screen than if I move it in the vertical direction (3.5/1.6 = 2.18 times further). How can I change this?

I have tried changing two settings:

- `Area`, [as suggested in a related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55170/wacom-bamboo-pen-scaling-issues), but this seems to affect only the active area of the physical tablet
- [`Coordinate Transformation Matrix`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Dual_and_Multi-Monitor_Set_Up#Coordinate_Transformation_Matrix), but this seems to only have an effect in Absolute mode.

Comment: We need to get this comment to the wacom mailing list.... forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending a message to the wacom developers mailing list:

> The two settings used above can not resolve the issue. It is a
> bug in X server/XInput.
>
> The problem lies in the difference between x, y scales. We used to
> unify the scale in wacom_drv.so when mapping and screen information
> were considered inside the driver (in linuxwacom package). The
> evidence of this work is still in the comments of xf86-input-wacom.
> Refer to line 611 of wcmCommon.c[*]. However, the actual scale match
> can not be fully implemented inside the driver any more since the new
> factorX/Y does not have screen info.
>
> Screen information and relative mode acceleration are pushed out into
> X server. Mapping and scale unification should be processed by in X
> server/Xinput too.
>
> So, by design, the scale is unified so users can draw circles in
> relative mode, without changing settings. - Ping Cheng ([Full Email](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29661199))

And then from Peter:

> yeah, that's a bug in the server, this should be exposed by the ptraccel
> code but it isn't yet. I've never found the time to properly investigate
> where it's going wrong, but you can even see this behaviour when you add a
> monitor - suddenly the acceleration factor goes up by a fair bit.
>
> As Ping said, this cannot be fixed in the driver, we need the server to
> handle this correctly. - Peter Hutterer ([Full Email](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29668336))

In conclusion, I think the best action is to report the bug and champion a developer to sort through the code to get a fix in place.